# What options are there to "push" to internet connected devices?

Tags: push-notification

I am working on a project that involves triggering actions on various internet connected devices such as phones, computers, home automation devices, etc. What technologies/general actions are available to connect devices like that? From my limited knowledge I can think of constant poling by all the devices, or making use of a prolonged HTTP connection (I believe that is somewhere along the lines of how Facebook does their notifications).

What other options do I have? What frameworks are there out there? Which option is the best when it comes to time from when the server wants to contact the device to when the device is actually contacted? Which option is easiest on the battery life of the devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For battery life, there's not much that beats a plain TCP socket connection. If you can do all the device's polling over a single connection, there is very little overhead besides a few bytes every x seconds for a keepalive packet (which you probably should either enable in the TCP stack or generate as a part of your protocol) This is afaik similar to what Apple uses for iOS notifications.

If you're in an environment where socket communication may be blocked by a firewall, I'd go for websockets with a fallback of long polling (which you mentioned in the question). Combined with proxy support, this should be able to traverse just about any firewall without much complication.